# Getting an Error as 'The given path's format is not supported'

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public void takeScreenshot()
    {
        ITakesScreenshot screenshotHandler = driver as  ITakesScreenshot;
        Screenshot screenshot = screenshotHandler.GetScreenshot();
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"D:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT" + DateTime.Now + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        screenshot.ToString();
    }
```

When i call the above method to get the screenshot in selenium, I am getting an Error as 'Message: NotSupportedExcetpion : The given path's format is not supported.'

Whats wrong with the path of the file.?

Comment: Can you share what are the image filenames like?

Comment: files doesn't already exists. I was trying to save the file during runtime. I just figured out the issue and it was the filename that was getting formed after appending DateTime.Now which was not a supported filename. thanks

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Now may return you the characters which are not valid for path in Windows. For Example you can get `DateTime.Now` result as `9/1/2016 11:41:19 AM`

and here you have prohibited chars:

- <, > (less than, greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- *(asterisk)

To achieve what you want you must provide path-friendly format for your DateTime. Example below:

```
string friendlyDatetime = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);
screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"D:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT" + friendlyDatetime + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I created a unique string to append to have a unique filename instead of using DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 0):

```
screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"D:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

This will save the files as follows:

> D:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT01-SEP-2016.png

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
public void takeScreenshot()
{
  string path = string.Format(@"c:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT{0:d_M_yyyy_HH_mm_ss}.txt", DateTime.Now);
  ITakesScreenshot screenshotHandler = driver as  ITakesScreenshot;
  Screenshot screenshot = screenshotHandler.GetScreenshot();     
  screenshot.SaveAsFile(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  screenshot.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're adding a DateTime to the string.

Try:

```
screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"D:\SeleniumTutorials\ScreenShotAT" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```